# When does a loop stop?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $n$ be a number. We define $X_k$ i.i.d. $U({1,2,\ldots,n})$ for $k=1,\ldots, n$, and $Y = \max \{m \mid k \leq X_k \forall k=1,\ldots,m\}$.

How can we find the distribution of $Y$? I have trouble working with the this $\max$ in the expression of $Y$.

This is motivated by the idea of writing a loop over the integers $1$ up to $n$, and throwing a $n$ sided dice each time to determine whether we continue: If the value of the dice is at least the number of the current step, we continue, otherwise we stop.

Comment: Isn't it straightforward? $P[Y \ge 1] = 1$. $P[Y \ge 2] = \frac {n-1} n$ (we fail for $k=2$ w.p. $\frac {n-1} n$). $P[Y \ge 3 ] = \frac {(n-1) (n-2)} {n^2}$ (we fail for $k=3$ w.p. $\frac {n-2} n$), etc.

Comment: The original expression does not have $n$ referencing  $k$ or $m$ in any way.  Is there a typo some where ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp there was a typo indeed, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Dmitry Yes I think that might be correct!